# MAthml tag gives error in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying ot add mathml tag into angular2 app.
my math ml code is

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mstyle displaystyle="true">
    <mfrac>
      <mrow>
        <mn>1</mn>
      </mrow>
      <mrow>
        <mn>2</mn>
      </mrow>
    </mfrac>
  </mstyle>
</math>
```

I am using Mathjax with config

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
</script>
```

Angular2 give error

```
zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
':math:mn' is not a known element:
1. If ':math:mn' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If ':math:mn' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
```

My app.modules.ts is

```
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule ,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Plz help, I could not figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you append the data after it created it should work.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'mathjax-display',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <p>testing mathjax</p>
    <div id="append"></div>
  `
})
export class MathjaxDisplayComponent {

  constructor(){

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    document.getElementById("append").innerHTML = `<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
         <semantics>
          <mrow>
           <mn>3</mn>
           <mo stretchy="false">/</mo>
           <mn>3</mn>
           <mo stretchy="false">⋅</mo>
           <mn>33</mn>
          </mrow>
          <annotation encoding="StarMath 5.0">3 / 3 cdot 33 </annotation>
         </semantics>
        </math>`;
  }
}
```